# Vector (array) addition in Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, vectorization

I have a column with `numeric[]` values which all have the same size. I'd like to take their element-wise average. By this I mean that the average of

```
{1, 2, 3}, {-1, -2, -3}, and {3, 3, 3}
```

should be `{1, 1, 1}`. Also of interest is how to sum these element-wise, although I expect that any solution for one will be a solution for the other.

(NB: The length of the arrays is fixed within a single table, but may vary between tables. So I need a solution which doesn't assume a certain length.)

My initial guess is that I should be using `unnest` somehow, since `unnest` applied to a `numeric[]` column flattens out all the arrays. So I'd like to think that there's a nice way to use this with some sort of windowing function + `group by` to pick out the individual components of each array and sum them.

```
-- EXAMPLE DATA
CREATE TABLE A
  (vector numeric[])
;

INSERT INTO A
  VALUES
    ('{1, 2, 3}'::numeric[])
    ,('{-1, -2, -3}'::numeric[])
    ,('{3, 3, 3}'::numeric[])
;
```

Answer (score 5):

I've written an extension to do vector addition (and subtraction, multiplication, division, and powers) with fast C functions. You can find it [on Github](https://github.com/pjungwir/floatvec) or [PGXN](https://pgxn.org/dist/floatvec/).

Given two arrays `a` and `b` you can say `vec_add(a, b)`. You can also add either side to a scalar, e.g. `vec_add(a, 5)`.

If you want a `SUM` aggregate function instead you can find that in [aggs_for_vecs](https://github.com/pjungwir/aggs_for_vecs), also on [PGXN](https://pgxn.org/dist/aggs_for_vecs).

Finally if you want to sum up all the elements of a single array, you can use [aggs_for_arrays](https://github.com/pjungwir/aggs_for_arrays) ([PGXN](https://pgxn.org/dist/aggs_for_arrays)).

Answer (score 4):

I discovered a solution on my own which is probably the one I will use.

First, we can define a function for adding two vectors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vec_add(arr1 numeric[], arr2 numeric[])
RETURNS numeric[] AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(result)
FROM (SELECT tuple.val1 + tuple.val2 AS result
      FROM (SELECT UNNEST($1) AS val1
                   ,UNNEST($2) AS val2
                   ,generate_subscripts($1, 1) AS ix) tuple
      ORDER BY ix) inn;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

and a function for multiplying by a constant:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vec_mult(arr numeric[], mul numeric)
RETURNS numeric[] AS
$$
SELECT array_agg(result)
FROM (SELECT val * $2 AS result
      FROM (SELECT UNNEST($1) AS val
                   ,generate_subscripts($1, 1) as ix) t
      ORDER BY ix) inn;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Then we can use the PostgreSQL statement `CREATE AGGREGATE` to create the `vec_sum` function directly:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE vec_sum(numeric[]) (
    SFUNC = vec_add
    ,STYPE = numeric[]
);
```

And finally, we can find the average as:

```
SELECT vec_mult(vec_sum(vector), 1 / count(vector)) FROM A;
```

Answer (score 1):

from http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4C2504A3.4090502@wp.pl

`select avg(unnested) from (select unnest(vector) as unnested from A) temp;`

---

Edit: I think I now understand the question better.

Here is a possible solution drawing heavily upon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/3430807 I don't consider it elegant nor am I sure it will perform well:

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
  (vector numeric[], id serial)
;

INSERT INTO A
  VALUES
    ('{1, 2, 3}'::numeric[])
    ,('{4, 5, 6}'::numeric[])
    ,('{7, 8, 9}'::numeric[])
;
```

Query:

```
select  avg(vector[temp.index])
from    A as a
join
    (select generate_subscripts(vector, 1) as index
              , id
        from    A) as temp on temp.id = a.id
group by temp.index
```

Comment: This is not what is desired at all. For one, it returns a `numeric` when I need a `numeric[]`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your expected results. Are you looking for the average of your arrays?

Comment: Yes, as per the third sentence of the post.

Comment: I reread your post. For the input {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} are you expecting {2,5,8} or {4,5,6}?

Comment: {4, 5, 6}. I will edit the post to make the example not ambiguous in this way.