# Element wise array addition in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL. I want to perform element-wise addition for the arrays(i.e. `col`) after grouping them by `time`. The arrays are of varying dimensions. Example as follows:

```
| time  | col               |
|------ |------------------ |
| 1     | {1,2}             |
| 1     | {3,4,5,6}         |
| 2     | {}                |
| 2     | {7}               |
| 2     | {8,9,10}          |
| 3     | {11,12,13,14,15}  |
```

The result should be as follows:

```
| time  | col               |
|------ |------------------ |
| 1     | {4,6,5,6}         |
| 2     | {15,9,10}         |
| 3     | {11,12,13,14,15}  |
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26391155/1615864) which does something similar for fixed dimension of 3 elements. But it does not work for varying dimensions.

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=905c752bfa76d222b1a23e6086d6db8f) for example.

Comment: This would be so much simpler with a properly normalized model. This is not the way arrays are meant to be used.

Comment: Normalize your data! Use a detail table to keep your variable sized data like arrays or look into mongodb

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What is the disadvantage of using arrays like this? I will read up more on normalizing the database. It will be helpful if you can provide me some good link for the same.

Comment: @DavidMunoz mongodb is not an option. I have to stick to PostgreSQL. I was under the impression that array operations are fast. If this is not true, I can use json objects or strings too. My final goal is to get a pair(s). Example, "0:300, 1:32, 3:0, 4:0, ..., 15:76 .."

Comment: [To quote the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html): "*Arrays are not sets*" - everytime you find yourself manipulating individual elements of an array or searching for specific elements in an array you are doing something wrong. You should treat an array as a "atomic value". The same you treat a column `firstname` as a single value. And before you de-normalize even more and mis-use JSON, you might want to read this: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use unnest with ordinality:

```
SELECT time, array_agg(elem order by nr)
FROM (SELECT time, nr, SUM(elem) AS elem
      FROM tab,unnest(col) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, nr)
      GROUP BY time,nr) s
GROUP BY time;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=da5d7133d3161a998ccf4484f842f817)**

Output:

```
┌──────┬──────────────────┐
│ time │    array_agg     │
├──────┼──────────────────┤
│    1 │ {4,6,5,6}        │
│    2 │ {15,9,10}        │
│    3 │ {11,12,13,14,15} │
└──────┴──────────────────┘
```

Comment: Why are the elements in the ARRAY_AGG [not ordered](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e4ff5472c5754215019d56f884a13eb9)?

Comment: @Vérace I am not sure if I follow you. They are ordered by its position not the value - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b610c6d6661eaaba8f1cb78634de7cac

Comment: Maybe it's the `SUM(elem)` that confused me - why is it there? You're not adding the elements?

Comment: And where did element 7 go?

Comment: @Vérace Elements are added by position, that was the whole point of the question. For instance for time =1 `{1,2}, {3,4,5,6} ` = `{1+3, 2+4, 5, 6}`

Comment: @Vérace and for time = 2 `{}, {7}, {8,9,10} ` => `{7+8, 9, 10}`

Comment: Thanks for your input!